# Can I fork a public Github project to a private BitBucket repository?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I want to fork a Github project and host it privately on a BitBucket account.

Can I still push/pull and all other commands from Github to BitBucket without any restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

BitBucket supports `git` so any `git` command will still work.

Things like issues and pull requests may be handled differently.

Also, be weary of the copyright of the repo your forking. Like, that goes anytime you do anything with someone else's code, but I would exercise extra caution in this case.